# NLog exception: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm using NLog. When I try to initialize my logger object like so:

```
private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

I get:

```
    2012-11-22 10:15:33.8479|Error|MyClass(6468:13)|MyNamespace.BaseThreadLoop|Exception processing event in RequestLoop: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MyClass' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at NLog.Internal.EnumerableHelpers.<OfType>d__0`1.MoveNext() in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\Internal\EnumerableHelpers.cs:line 60
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at NLog.Internal.EnumerableHelpers.ToList[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable) in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\Internal\EnumerableHelpers.cs:line 118
   at NLog.Internal.ObjectGraphScanner.ScanProperties[T](List`1 result, Object o, Int32 level, Dictionary`2 visitedObjects) in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\Internal\ObjectGraphScanner.cs:line 118
   at NLog.Internal.ObjectGraphScanner.ScanProperties[T](List`1 result, Object o, Int32 level, Dictionary`2 visitedObjects) in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\Internal\ObjectGraphScanner.cs:line 125
   at NLog.Internal.ObjectGraphScanner.ScanProperties[T](List`1 result, Object o, Int32 level, Dictionary`2 visitedObjects) in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\Internal\ObjectGraphScanner.cs:line 125
   at NLog.Internal.ObjectGraphScanner.ScanProperties[T](List`1 result, Object o, Int32 level, Dictionary`2 visitedObjects) in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\Internal\ObjectGraphScanner.cs:line 125
   at NLog.Internal.ObjectGraphScanner.FindReachableObjects[T](Object[] rootObjects) in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\Internal\ObjectGraphScanner.cs:line 65
   at NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain.PrecalculateStackTraceUsage() in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\Internal\TargetWithFilterChain.cs:line 95
   at NLog.LogFactory.GetTargetsByLevelForLogger(String name, IList`1 rules, TargetWithFilterChain[] targetsByLevel, TargetWithFilterChain[] lastTargetsByLevel) in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\LogFactory.cs:
line 587
   at NLog.LogFactory.GetTargetsByLevelForLogger(String name, IList`1 rules, TargetWithFilterChain[] targetsByLevel, TargetWithFilterChain[] lastTargetsByLevel) in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\LogFactory.cs:
line 574
   at NLog.LogFactory.GetConfigurationForLogger(String name, LoggingConfiguration configuration) in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\LogFactory.cs:line 599
   at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(LoggerCacheKey cacheKey) in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\LogFactory.cs:line 717
   at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(String name) in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\LogFactory.cs:line 330
   at NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger() in c:\NLogBuild\src\NLog\LogManager.cs:line 143
   at MyNamespace.MyOtherClass..cctor() in C:\....cs:line 25
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MyNamespace.MyClass.get_Instance()
   ...
```

I followed the suggestion at http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/InvalidOperationException-when-accessing-the-configuration-from-multiple-threads-td6723806.html to move my memory target to a separate class but still having the issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using an old version of NLog. Can you check the NLog file `src/NLog/Internal/ObjectGraphScanner.cs` you rely on (or look into the assembly with a tool such as .NET reflector)?

It should be like what's displayed in green in this bug fix:

[BUG 6015: InvalidOperationException (Collection was modified) in call…](https://github.com/jkowalski/NLog/commit/1eed9951496bffb1fc08ec9c4cad591c6bb48c68)

Comment: I haven't verified this yet but sounds like it will resolve the issue so awarding bounty now in case I forget. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I looked in .NET reflector and see --                                 foreach (object obj3 in enumerable.OfType<object>().ToList<object>())
 -- so it looks like it is not this

Comment: Mhhhh... Looks like a similar bug but somewhere else. Are you running multithreaded? If yes, could you try to put the _logger initialization in a lock() ?

Comment: The issue is occurring in OfType which is getting called when EnumerableHelpers.ToList is called. So it is calling ToList but that ends up calling OfType which then iterates through the enumerable. Can this be safely simplified? The code is at https://github.com/jkowalski/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Internal/EnumerableHelpers.cs. Also all this starts from PrecalculateStackTraceUsage ("find all objects which may need stack trace") so do I even need this if I get the stack dumps myself?